# How to call SQL queries with multiple variable in the localhost server?

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a java function which performs a SQL query:

```
SELECT usernum, username, uniquenum 
FROM table 
WHERE username = ? AND uniqenum = ?
```

In my localhost I can call the similar function with one variable as `http://localhost:8080/listUsers?uniqenum=5` but how can I call a function with two variables?

I have tried `http://localhost:8080/listUsers?username="John"&uniqenum=5` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide the java function. It looks like you are simply extracting data from a query string. To best assist you, you'll need to provide more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Java code is set up to take `GET` requests properly, all you really need to do is remove the double quotes.

```
http://localhost:8080/listUsers?username=John&uniqenum=5
```

Comment: Note that if quotations are desired, they should actually be URL encoded into their equivalent %22 and not translated literally.